# $|x+y|^p+|x-y|^p\ge\alpha |x|^p+\alpha|y|^p$

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

I am interested in the relation between the sum of the $p$-th power of the diagonals of a parallelogram and the $p$-th power of its sides. More precisely, given the standard Euclidean distance $|x|=\|x\|_2$, what is the biggest $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x+y|^p+|x-y|^p\ge\alpha |x|^p+\alpha|y|^p$.

In the case $p=2$, we have the parallelogram identity that gives us $|x+y|^2+|x-y|^2=2 |x|^2+2|y|^2$ but what about general case $p\ge 1$?

Comment: Parallelogram identity is for $p=2$ and you are missing some powers on the left side.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thank you I edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $p\geq1$, let $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$ so that $x=\frac{u+v}{2}$ and $y=\frac{u-v}{2}$. Recall Jensen's inequality: $\big(\frac{a+b}{2}\big)^p\leq \frac12(a^p+b^p)$ for all $a,b\geq0$. Then
$$\Big|\frac{u+v}{2}\Big|^p+\Big|\frac{u-v}{2}\Big|^p\leq\frac{1}{2}(|u|^p+|v|^p)+\frac{1}{2}(|u|^p+|v|^p)=|u|^p+|v|^p$$

In gereral, $|u\pm v|\leq 2\max\{|u|,|v|\}$. For any $p>0$, $x\mapsto x^p$ is monotone increasing. Then
$$\begin{align}
\Big|\frac{u+v}{2}\Big|^p+\Big|\frac{u-v}{2}\Big|^p & \leq 
\frac{1}{2^p}(2^p\max\{|u|^p,|v|^p\})+
\frac{1}{2^p}(2^p\max\{|u|^p,|v|^p\})\\
&=2\max\{|u|^p,|v|^p\}\leq 2(|u|^p+|v|^p)\end{align}$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you. For $p\ge 1$ this is the best we can do?

Comment: I believe so. One has to look for instance at the "optimal" Minkowsky inequality.